# (Programmatically, Silent mode)SQL Sever Setup failure, the configuration file 'xxx' does not exist

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008-r2

I am doing a silent mode sql installation by running my code.

It runs fine and every file is extracted from the installer, after that it pops up an error message.
[image]

I opened that folder and did not find the file. But I have the file in my Debug folder.(I manually created it.)
By looking at the folder name, it seems like a randomly created name.

So the question is **how can I get the folder name which the SQL installer going to create?**(so I can copy the configuration.ini to it)

Comment: I think this is the last obstacle I need to overcome, someone helps please.

Comment: @DarkoKenda Hi Darko, thank you for asking. The reason why I didn't put my code was I thought it wasn't the problem from my code but a problem for the SQL Installer. Now I have fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

It was a problem in my code.

```
//Process p = Process.Start(Resources.MSSQLSERVER_LOCAL_PATH, Resources.SQLSERVER_INI);

 Process p = Process.Start(Resources.MSSQLSERVER_LOCAL_PATH, "/ConfigurationFile=" + System.IO.Path.Combine(System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), "ConfigurationFile.ini") + " /ACTION=Install");
```

Now I use the second code, it works fine for me.